# creating pages on each current blog site on plugin activation

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am on a project which will create pages while activating the plugin.
But it is creating on existing main blog site. It also want to create in existing blog sites automatically on plugin activation.

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs");

foreach($query as $result) {

    switch_to_blog($result->blog_id);

    wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: have u tried something ?? paste some code ??

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`plugin activation hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)

Please, also, review your message, it is unclear.